# Why is there pressure difference when the liquid surface is curved?

Tags: surface-tension

I also want to know why such pressure difference do not occur when the liquid surface is plane even though there are different mediums at both sides of the surface.

Answer (score 2):

The pressure is due to the surface tension, and the force in surface tension always acts tangentially to the plane of the surface. If you consider a curved surface:

[image: Curved surface]

then in general the component of the force, $F_x$, normal to the surface will be non-zero and this causes the pressure in, for example, a bubble.

On the other hand if the surface is completely flat:

[image: Flat surface]

then there cannot be any net force acting normal to the surface so the surface tension cannot cause a pressure change.

Comment: From my point of view introducing molecules usually serves much better at explaining surface tension